# Como mostrar los datos de PHP en ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando cargar los datos de PHP en la pagina cuando esta termine de cargarse, pero no me muestra los datos, aqui tengo un ejemplo sencillo:

```
<?php
   $datos = new stdClass();
   $datos->mensaje = "hola";
   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   $json= json_encode($datos);

   echo $json;
?>
```

ese es tomardatos.php, aqui el codigo ajax

```
window.onload = function () {
    $.getJSON("Tomardatos.php", exito);
};

function exito(data) {

    alert(data.mensaje);
}
```

vi por ahi que .getJSON es para obtener datos del servidor, pero no funciona, espero su ayuda, gracias :)

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Estás planteando mal la cosa: el primer bloque de código que muestras debe ser el de `Tomardatos.php` y el segundo bloque debe ser al archivo que se abre en el cliente (la página web a la que entras por una URL). Es desde esa página que mandas a pedir los datos al servidor en este caso mediante `$.getJSON`. Actualmente le estás mandando la petición a ella misma.

Answer (score 3):

Debes llamar a la libreria de jQuery para que funcione, prueba asi:

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
 $.getJSON("Tomardatos.php", exito);
};

function exito(data) {
  alert(data.mensaje);
}

</script>
```

getJson no es una función nativa de javaScript. Lo probé y me lanzo el alet con "hola", espero te funcione.